# Could not authorize while connecting to the SonarQube server. Check your credentials and try again

Tags: xamarin.forms, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run SonarQube for my Xamarin Forms project, I am on the path where my .SLN file is there and executing the following command

Command:

$ mono /Users/akandasamy/Development/HIDProjects/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"HIDReaderManagerApp" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="My Login Token"

Error:

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
Default properties file was found at /Users/akandasamy/Development/HIDProjects/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /Users/akandasamy/Development/HIDProjects/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.0.2.892/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
17:29:10.391  Updating build integration targets...
17:29:10.414  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
**17:29:10.517  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values?component=HIDReaderManagerApp': The remote server returned an error: (401) .
17:29:10.517  Could not authorize while connecting to the SonarQube server. Check your credentials and try again.
17:29:10.518  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `api/settings/values` API requires `Browse` permission when the `component` argument is used. Please, see if the user you are authenticating with has the aforementioned permission.

More details about security and permissions here:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security

Comment: Thanks, Valeri, I think this is to do with permission I was supplying wrong credentials on the login and when I gave the right user in my case admin, it got worked...But now I am getting a strange issue, I doubt this is something with SonarCube or in the code.

I am getting like 

Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Line 523 is out of range in the file my.CS file (lines: 522)

Comment: If the answer of Valeri solves your issue, please accept it, and create another question for the scanner issue. Thanks

Comment: Where I will configure this permission? I'm faced with same issue

Comment: Hi @Ricardo, please check this page for more information: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security on security abd permissions. If this does not help, I suppose my former colleagues would be able to help you much better than me if you ask a question here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/. Cheers!